# How can I make an immutable Array in swift that has different instances of the same class

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode6

So in swift there isn't a distinct difference between an Array, and a mutable Array, but the Apple docs say it is always better to use an immutable Array when you know the number of elements.  So say I want to make an immutable Array of type Hi that has x different elements of type Hi.

I can do this but it will assign the same instance to each element in the array

```
var array = [Hi](count: x, repeatedValue: Hi())
```

I can do this but the elements in the array are let, and therefore not editable

```
var array = [Hi](count: x, repeatedValue: nil)
for hi in array {
hi = Hi()
}
```

Is there a constructor for Array that takes a closure so I can tell it how to make each element?

Comment: `hi = Hi()` doesn't make any sense, `hi` is a local variable, you need to assign to `array[i]`. `for i in 0..x { array[i] = Hi() }`

Comment: It's in a for in loop which iterates over the array

Comment: Your loop iterates over the *contents* of the array.  You need to loop over the indices of the array.

Comment: Also, you can't initialize the contents of your array to `nil` because the values are not `optional` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an expression, simply:

```
[Int](count: x, repeatedValue: 0).map { _ in Hi() }
```

or, more succinctly, as suggested by @vacawama and using Range.map

```
(1...x).map { _ in Hi() }
```

Comment: Thanks that map method was just what I was looking for :)

Comment: And you can use `_` instead of `x` since you're not going to use it

Comment: You're making two arrays when you only need one. This could bite you if `x` is really large. Try: `Array(map(1...x, { _ in Hi() }))` (warning: typed on phone, may need tweaking)

Comment: Nice! As a group we came up with a very nice answer. This is what makes StackOverflow so awesome!